# sync files between docker container and host machine

Tags: python-3.x, docker, flask, docker-compose, docker-volume

The scenario is; I have a folder `static` and it contains one file named `sample_old.txt` and mounted `static` to the container using `docker-compose.yml` . Then I start my docker services using `docker-compose up`. Then called a function to create a new file named `sample_new.txt` inside the `static` folder.As a result, it generated the new file inside static ( verified by getting into the container using `sudo docker exec -it container_id bash` ) But the problem is, the newly generated file is only available in the container not in host os.

How can I make available the newly generated file inside the container to host? Can I sync the directory all the time? I don't know whether it possible or not. If possible please provide a solution .

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3"
services:

  web:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    command: "python my_celery.py"
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    networks:
      - webnet
    volumes:
      - .:/celery_sample
      - /static:/celery_sample/static

networks:
  webnet:
```

**directory structure- host os**

```
.
├── docker-compose.yml
├── Dockerfile
├── __init__.py
├── my_celery.py 
├── README.md
├── requirements.txt
└── static
    └── sample_old.txt
```

**directory structure- container**

```
.
    ├── docker-compose.yml
    ├── Dockerfile
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── my_celery.py 
    ├── README.md
    ├── requirements.txt
    └── static
        └── sample_old.txt
        └── sample_new.txt
```

**flask-fucnction for file generation**

```
@flask_app.route('/text')
def generate_file():
    file_dir_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "static")
    if not os.path.exists(file_dir_path):
        os.mkdir(file_dir_path)
    with open(os.path.join(file_dir_path, "sample_new.txt"), "wb+") as fo:
        fo.write("This is just s test".encode())
    return "Writed to file"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in the `docker-compose.yml` file that is not well defined; you are missing a `.` in the definition of the `static` mount point, it should be `./static` because it is in the current working directory.

```
services:
  web:
    ...
    - ./static:/celery_sample/static
```

Answer (score 0):

I use the great [docker-sync](https://github.com/EugenMayer/docker-sync) library at work and I love it for development and two way data syncing. It uses [Unison](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/) to quickly sync the files between the container and your local files.

Comment: Is there any alternative way which can be done by **Dockerfile** or **docker-compose.yml** ?